# Is the viewing (author.php) page user the matching user?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently playing around with Wordpress user's profile pages `author.php` and would like to implement a personal information front-end edit ability for users AND public statistical user data fallback for any other user viewing the page.

I'm looking for a secure way to determine if the user currently viewing the `author.php` user page, is the matching user.

Right now I'm comparing `get_current_user_id()` with `get_queried_object()->ID`.

If the ID's match, I'm revealing a specific sensible personal (credentials, emails ...) content. If not, I'm just showing some basic statistical data.

The following is just a minimal working representation from an `author.php` page.

```php
<?php 
if ( get_current_user_id() === get_queried_object()->ID )
    echo "You're the one!";
else
    echo "Lies!";
?>
```

**Should I be checking for anything else beside the ID, before showing any personal information ?**

---

### Edit

Following @Xhynk answer, here is what I'm currently using:

```php
<?php if ( get_queried_object() instanceof \WP_User && get_current_user_id() === get_queried_object()->ID ) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}; ?>
```

Comment: might want to also check the user is logged in with `is_user_logged_in()` more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: @mikerojas, `get_current_user_id()` already checks if the user is logged in with `wp_get_current_user()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id) will already accurately, and securely, get the logged in user's ID - there isn't really a way to override it without having server level access (aka, you can override it in a plugin/theme, but can't from the client).

One thing to consider though is that you may want to check that the [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object) is actually a `WP_User`, because the queried object can be a Term, Post Type, Post, or User, and those ID's are *not* exclusive.

For instance, there can be a `post` with ID `1`, a user with ID `1`, and a term with ID `1`, all 3 of which aren't really correlated.

If you're putting this in `author.php`, it's not a huge concern as the Template Hierarchy will essentially handle that for you, but if you ever made this function more abstract to expand it and moved it to `functions.php` or somethiung, you'd want to consider doing it, or do it now for an added level of "not forgetting to later".

One last bit is that you'll want to validate the data that's submitted from the front end regardless of the above, and make sure that the current indeed does have access to edit the information that's being sent and updated.

In short:

- You should be okay showing the front-end editing as you are now (but I'd consider adding a redundant check for the queried object's type)
- You should be validating the data sent to make sure the current user has appropriate permissions anyway, whether or not they can see the front-end editing

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `get_queried_object()` | [Retrieves the currently queried object.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object) |
| `get_current_user_id()` | [Get the current user’s ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id) |

Comment: Thank you for the `WP_User` int, that's a fair and valid point!

Comment: For future references, and thanks to @Xhynk, here is what I'm using: `if ( get_queried_object() instanceof \WP_User && get_current_user_id() === get_queried_object()->ID )`